# Obj / Array element notation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don’t know what it is called or I would look it up, but when acsessing an object or arrays element in jQuery what is the differance between Obj.element and Obj[”element”]?

Comment: They are called [Object property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors). They are the same, both try to access a property named `element`

Comment: Bracket notation. That's what it's called specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Obj.element and Obj[”element”]
```

Both these will access the same key element inside object Obj. Value against key name "element" will be returned.

Comment: @IsaacS.Weaver Well, arrays are just objects with the keys 0, 1, 2, etc. You can't do arr.0 so you do arr[0]. It's the same operation.

Comment: Note `arr[0]` is equivalent to `arr["0"]`, as property names are strings (or symbols)

Comment: @IsaacS.Weaver dot notation doesn't work on arrays, although arrays are objects with keys starting from 0 and incrementing for every push operation.

Comment: Perfect that answers my question completely! Thank you all!!